# Does blinding cloud completely disable siege tanks in siege mode?

Tags: starcraft-2

Blinding cloud reduces attack range of anything under the cloud to "melee".

Since sieged tanks have a minimum range, does this disable them completely?

Comment: "does this disable them completely?" It only stops them from attacking. They can still unsiege/siege while in blinding cloud.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [teamliquid wiki](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Viper):

> Blinding Cloud is especially useful against Siege Tanks, as the tanks
>   must un-siege in order to move out of the cloud, effectively removing
>   them from the battle.

While it says they must un-siege in order to move out of the cloud, this does not mean they cannot siege. But yes, they are completely unable to attack in siege mode.

Answer (score 3):

[Binding Cloud will reduce all units within the cloud to a range of 1 aka melee](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Viper).   But here is the kicker. [Siege Tanks of a minimum range of 2 in Siege Mode](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Siege_Tank_Modes), therefore will not be able to attack until they unsiege, or until the spell wears off.

I do not like the term 'disable' because it is truly not disabled.  Disabled makes it sound like it will *never* work again in which it will.  It's just while the spell is in affect, it must unsiege to attack because its range is less than its minimum range.